# read tables with thousands of columns from mysql to dataframe in python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I need to read table with 500+ columns and 1000~ rows from mysql to python. I was using pandas.io.sql.read_frame but it gave an error.

(, AssertionError('Protocol error, expecting EOF',))

However, no error occurred when I reduced the number of columns to 200~. Could someone help me with a solution to read such large tables?

Comment: There is a hard limit of 4096 columns per table in MySQL. Either your question is wrong (typo?), or..

Comment: @geertjanvdk Oops, I think it should be 500+ columns. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Which MySQL Python database driver was used? Which MySQL version?

Comment: Can you also provide a full example and error traceback? And which pandas verision?